# rotate animation 120 degrees at time, raphael, javascript

Tags: javascript, raphael

I Created an animation with raphael and javascript.
I want the animation to rotate 120 degrees at the time, but I cant only get it to rotate 120 degrees once and then it stop

Any ideas how to get it rotate 
This is my javascript.

```
        var paper;
        var rect1;
        var rect2;
        var xEnd;
        var xEnd2;
var angleF = "120"
var angleB = "-120"
        function init()
        {
            paper = Raphael("ritYta");
            // Bakgrund
            var bg = paper.rect( 0, 0, "240px", "90px", 0 );
            bg.attr( {fill: "#f3f3ff"} );
                            // Skapa rektangel 1
            rect1 = paper.rect(150, 20, 50, 50);
            rect1.attr( {fill: "#ffaaaa", "stroke-width": 3} );
            xEnd = 150;
            rect2 = paper.rect(20, 20, 50, 50);
            rect2.attr( {fill: "#aaaaff", "stroke-width": 3} );

        };

        function moveRect1()
        {       
            // Reverse.uppfÖrande
            if( xEnd == 150 )
                xEnd = 50;
            else
                xEnd = 150;

            // x heter x på rektanglar. Vänstra övre hönet.
            rect1.animate( {x: xEnd},                       // det/de attribut som ska animeras, och till vilket värde.
                            1000,                                   // tid
                            "Sine",                         // Ease funktion
function (){ moveRect1(); } // Anropa sig själv för att få upprepning.
        ); // slut på animate
        }

function stopRect1() {
            rect1.stop();
    };


function rotRect2F(){

rect2.animate({transform: " r " + angleF}, 2000, "bounce");
}
    function rotRect2B(){
rect2.animate({transform: " r " + angleB}, 2000, "bounce");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To raphael the shape is already rotated to 120degs, so it doesn't do anything. You need to sum these rotations so the first one is 120deg, 240deg, 360deg, etc.

```
rect2.animate({transform: "... r120"}, 2000, "bounce");
}
    function rotRect2B(){
rect2.animate({transform: "... r-120"}, 2000, "bounce");
    }
```

The ellipsis `...` means Raphael will add this rotation to whatever transformation is already applied.

Comment: Its working good, but when i rotate it back it just flips out :).
Going to investigate it by my self.
Thanks allot mr

Comment: Ah, then you're going to need the same variable to rotate back, i.e. `angleF-=120` so it subtracts from the current rotation.

Comment: Yes indeed, I did that but It seems that for every time I press forward it ad the value, so if i press forward 4 times the value is 120X4 = 480 . so when Im pressing the back button It rotate -600 degrees back instead of 120 degrees.  did you get what I mean :)?

Comment: I found an easier method to apply the rotation, see updated answer.

Comment: Thats awsome, the whole animation is going smoother.
Thanks